# Display user meta data that is an array?

Tags: arrays, wordpress, metadata

I have a custom field on my user account page that is called "color" and it's made with checkboxes where the user can chose a color.

normally i get the user data this way when i have a simple text field:

```
<?php if ( $themeta != $user->color ) echo '<li><strong>Color:</strong> ' . $user->color . '</li>'; ?>
```

This gives me just the word "Array" when i use checkboxes. So it knows the data comes as an array, but how to display the data?

Comment: if it's only one value set the `$single` parameter of [get_user_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) to true. Otherwise loop through the array.

Comment: it can be one value but it also can be more values.

Answer (score 0):

Okay the code for the array has to look like this:

```
<?php
    $values = $user->color;
    if (isset($values)) {

    echo "<strong>Color:</strong> ";

    foreach($values as $value)
    {
    echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
    }
    }
?>
```